# while loop execution stops after one iteration within bash script

Tags: shell-script

i have bash script(1.sh) which calls (2.sh) within a while loop.
Execution stops after just one iteration. if i remove call to 2.sh it executes perfectly

my code
1.sh

```
while read -a A ; do
        echo "${GREEN}  Making production build for ${A[0]} ${NC}"
        # run build for each component
        ./2.sh ${A[0]} ${A[1]}

        if [[ $? -eq 1 ]]; then
            # create logs of error builds
            ERRORBUILDS+=${A[0]}" ,"

        fi
    done < $1
```

Comment: Probably 2.sh reads from its stdin (that happens for instance if you call ssh without -n). You may want to read the content of `$1` on a different file descriptor and close it within the loop. See examples at [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/169765)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas sir, a correction in the code(build.sh to 2.sh). Could you please explicitly mention what changes i have to make.

Comment: It could be just a matter of redirecting `2.sh`'s stdin from /dev/null (add `< /dev/null`). The question would we why it reads from its stdin and what it expects to find there.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thank you for the solution. How to upvote your answer as the right answer

Answer (score 2):

```
./2.sh < /dev/null ${A[0]} ${A[1]}
```

Comment: [Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Quoted variables would be safer, too, unless you _really know why_ you don't want to quote them. Consider `./2.sh < /dev/null "${A[0]}" "${A[1]}"` instead.

Comment: This solved  my similar problem, but now I want to know why.
Is there a wiping of  input?

Comment: I guess the subshell somehow inherits and consumes stdin. I still find that very odd, too, and just spent hours on bugs caused by that.

Comment: basically, if the script calls any command that might use stdin you get conflicts, such as `du` or `grep`, because it is often silently swallowed... even if it runs in a subshell like `$()`